# Null pointer exception while fetching firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
        DatabaseReference mFetchingMessages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);


     FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MessagesHelper> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessagesHelper>()
                    .setQuery(mFetchingMessages, MessagesHelper.class)
                    .build();

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessagesHelper, Chat.MessagesViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Chat.MessagesViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull MessagesHelper model) {
            holder.setMessage(model.getMessage());
            final String from_user = model.getFrom();
            final boolean Seen = model.isSeen();

            final String userId = getRef(position).getKey();
            DatabaseReference mTimeReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
            mTimeReference.keepSynced(true);
            mTimeReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String message = postSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();

                        if (from_user != null && from_user.equals(MessageSenderId)) {
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mDisplayMessage.getLayoutParams();
                            params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setLayoutParams(params);

                            if (Seen == true) {
                                holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            } else {
                                holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mDisplayMessage.getLayoutParams();
                            params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setLayoutParams(params);
                        }

                        holder.setMessage(message);
                        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public Chat.MessagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_chat, parent, false);
            return new Chat.MessagesViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    messageList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

 public static class MessagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    TextView mDisplayMessage;
    public MessagesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        mDisplayMessage = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
        mDisplayMessage.setText(String.valueOf(message));
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
    }
}
```

If i remove the loop it will fetch only the last message... Like the all the views will show only the last message  and if i add loop  im getting a nullpointer exception on the line String message = postsnapshot.child("Message")

[image]

First is the senders id inside messages and inside that is recievers id and inside that is push id

Comment: your `postsnapshot` is null I guess

Comment: But its not null... see the database @Kartik

Comment: POST your `Logcat`

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't see the full question

Comment: This happens when your all children don't have `Message` attribute. Double check your nodes, maybe any node has missing `Message` child

Comment: Your database structure seems to be: `/$senderid/$receiverid/$messageid`. When you create an adapter on `/$senderid/$receiverid`, that adapter will take care of the `$messageid`s unde there. So you don't need the `for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {` loop. I also highly doubt you need to create a new listener in `onBindViewHolder`. Please try removing both, and update your question with what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line to your code to check if you have `Message` child then pick it up.

It seems your some nodes do not have `Message` child. You can check it before fetching `Message`.

```
if (postSnapshot.hasChild("Message")) {
     String message = postSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();
}
```